# explanation of topology examples from movie or other

Tags: general-topology, popular-math

I always like topology and geometry.
But there are some examples in film and videogames that upset me...

1)Imagine an empty room in which there is a door in the middle, and if I open it I can see a room inside. (like the TARDIS in Doctor Who)

2) Like in this videogame https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v4JxhiNz8ec (watch from the 1:00, for a minute at least) there is a maze in which the different directions do not overlap and you can return back from different path!

The last example comes from this videogame:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antichamber

There are other examples, but I cannot translate to english T_T

However, I want to formalize these kind of rooms from a geometrical (or topological?) point of view! I like this type of worldbuilding but I dont know 
anything, since I am a physicyst (not a theoretical!).
What kind of books do you suggest? I can study but I prefer not to do so much :D
Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but [Jeff Weeks'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffrey_Weeks_%28mathematician%29) [_The Shape of Space_](http://www.worldcat.org/title/shape-of-space/oclc/50817378) is relevant, and a good read. His [software page](http://geometrygames.org/) may also be of interest.

Comment: Have you played Portal?

Comment: I did. I did not think while I was writing this. Of course in that game there is another example of a strange geometry that deserves attention.
@tim: I will try that book, seems interesting. Thank you. I hope is simple :P

Answer (score 2):

This book:

http://www.amazon.ca/The-Shape-Space-Jeffrey-Weeks/dp/0824707095

along with this software:

http://www.geometrygames.org/CurvedSpaces/index.html

should give you a pretty great understanding of the topology of manifolds.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Haha yeah, I was blown away when my friend showed this to me. I played around on the software for hours.

Comment: You too post that book, so it should be a MUST :D
That software is very cool! it blow my mind xD